# Increase size of Annotation In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm trying to increase the size of a MKPointAnnotation after I touch it.

Right now I use the following code:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        print("annotation deselected")
        if let garageAnnantion = view.annotation as? GarageAnnoation {
             view.image = UIImage(named: "greenPinBig")

          }
      }
```

This works, however. **It will make the view animate the size in a weird way**.

Any idea of how I can fix this?